# Bash: How can I display the content of an environment variable from within a script?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I can find lots of source about how to set environment variables but, i'm looking to display a variable rather than set it.

I've wrote a custom `motd` file and I want it to display the `$LOCATION` environment variable in the output of the `motd` script, how is it done please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I'm misunderstanding, but...?

```
echo $LOCATION
```

Comment: Seems like there was some hiding variable with the same name, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/motd` is a static file. You can [generate it with another script](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Motd), but as far as I can tell `login` won't expand anything in that file.